# How to print a one2many field values in qweb report in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, qweb

I am trying to print a one2many field values one by one separated by comma,

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
<strong>Attendees:</strong>
<p t-esc="o.matp.empname"/>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this and also wanted to print values separated by comma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<t t-foreach='o.matp' t-as='value'>
      <t t-esc="value.empname"/>,
</t>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jainik patel

Comment: Jainik , table outer borders are not visible ? any idea on that ?

Comment: <table border="1" style="width:100%;">

Comment: <p t-field="o.nxt_mt"/> how to give substitue value to display on the qweb , suppose i want to display '-' if o.nxt_mt does not have a value ?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function in your parser of qweb report and call that function from report, which returns a comma separated list of values to your report.

Comment: Hardik Patadia, yes i agree, Thank you very much